# jQuery: Assign background colors to elements

Tags: jquery, colors

I'm very new to jQuery, and I'd like to set the background color of elements according to their value at page load.

Each of the elements have an `id` ending with `"*_hex"` that's why I use the selector `$("[id$=_hex]")`, and each have a `value` that is a hex color.

Here is an exemple element:

```
<input id="product_colors_attributes_382873_hex" type="text" value="#c22424">
```

And here's the code I've come up with so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("[id$=_hex]").each(function(){
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', $(this).value);
    });
});
```

It works if I hardcode the color, but obviously `$(this).value` doesn't work. 
Any clues?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `this.value`, no need for jQuery to get value of an input.

Answer (score 3):

use `val()` instead of `$(this).value`

```
 $(this).val()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).css('backgroundColor', $(this).val());
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the value field with jquery you should use the function val()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("[id$=_hex]").each(function(){
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', $(this).val());
    });
});
```